# java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)

Tags: java, linux, vtk, jogl, install4j

Running linux Mint 64bit, using Install4j to wrap a VTK JOGL JAVA program to a Linux distribution, I get this crash on launch:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.util.ArgumentStack.popString(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Am I interpreting this right as if the runtime encounters and error and runs into another error while trying to output the stack?

edit: I should mention that I'm not getting the error message in my usual error.log, but had to rewire the error output to get anything error message at all for the crash

Comment: I know nothing about install4j or VTK or JOGL but judging from the stacktrace, it looks like you are missing some program arguments when invoking your jar.

Comment: Oh, crap. That makes a lot of sense. I thought I rewired the output error, but instead I just botched the arguments when invoking the jar.

The actual problem now is that the program crashes without any error message and I can't find any in /var/log/ or anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Tunaki said, I botched some arguments when invoking the jar which caused this crash (and not the one I was looking for). Solved